# Am I missing step in building/installing VTK-5.4 with Python2.6 bindings on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I successfully built and installed VTK-5.4 with Python bindings from source. Yet, when I try to import VTK in python it gives the following Traceback error

> File "", line 1, in
>
> File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/VTK-5.4.2-py2.6.egg/vtk/**init**.py",
>    line 41, in   from common import *
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/VTK-5.4.2-py2.6.egg/vtk/common.py",
>     line 7, in    from libvtkCommonPython import *
>
> ImportError:
>    libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I am wondering what I am missing? I have tried adding /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.4 to both PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables and still get the same result. Any hints or suggestions?

NOTE:
*libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.4* exists in /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.4 as a symlink to *libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.4.2*

Comment: Does libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.4 file actually exist on your disk?

Comment: yes it exists and lives in /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test if adding `/usr/local/lib` to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` helps:

In a shell:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

If it works, make it permanent by (adding `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`) _ (running '`ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib`')

Comment: well, adding /usr/local/lib didn't work BUT adding /usr/local/lib/vtk-5.4 did. thanks!

Comment: i might have missed the trailing slash over there,
adding the directory should be enough (and will help your system find other libraries which after compilation get copied to /usr/local/lib/). Glad it worked!