# vtk build succeeds but python says module doesn't exist?

Tags: python, vtk

I'm building [vtk](http://www.vtk.org) on Cent OS. I would like to install the python wrappers, and I've followed the [build directions](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Linux) to do so.

I've installed under prefix `~/local`. Things appear to have gone successfully:

`vtk`, `vtkpython`, and other vtk executables appear in my `~/local/bin/` directory. vtk libraries appear in `~/local/lib`.

However, when I run `python -c "import vtk"`, I see:

> ImportError: No module named vtk

So apparently, something is not correctly pointing to something else, although I'm not sure what I'm missing since I've followed the build directions.

Here is the value of a particular shell variable that seems to show up on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956716/am-i-missing-step-in-building-installing-vtk-5-4-with-python2-6-bindings-on-ubun):

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
=> ~/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where is the python module. In my system (where VTK was not built following those instructions, but should not be too different) there is a folder in lib/python2.6/site-packages/vtk/ , which contains `__init__.py` and all the vtk classes (e.g vtkCommonCore.py , vktCommonCorePython.so ..).
If you find that folder, add its parent folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable (or in your python distribution site-packages folder, create a file vtk.pth which contains that folder). 
So, in my system, I have:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/mypath/INSTALL/lib/python2.6/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
```

See also http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/PythonEnvironmentSetup

Comment: You're right. The build created a `lib/python2.6/` folder which contained nothing but `site-packages/vtk`. I'm a little confused why this is, but in any case I moved the `vtk` folder to `lib/python/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is my working python library directory, and things seems to be working fine now.